# Escaping single quote character in SQLite database names

Tags: sqlite

Assuming that I have a database with names Main, AA and A'A. Both have a table named MyTable.
The Main database was opened originally and AA and A'A are attached afterwards.
I can use `select * from 'AA'.'MyTable'`, but I found no way to address the A'A database similarly.
The 'A'A' or 'A''A' did not work. I do not insist escaping the ' character but I need to be able to address all possible valid database names.

Comment: In theory `"A'A".MyTable` should work but it appears not to.  Have you considered using an alias? E.g `ATTACH DATABASE "C:\foo\A'A.db" AS AA;` then use the alias thereafter: `SELECT * FROM AA.MyTable`

Comment: Using alias is possible, but not a perfect solution for me. In my case I have a framework application, that fills up part of the sql script like (<> is the placeholder):
select * from <MyProject>_SomePersistedSystemData.SomeData.KnownTable,
and I am looking for an in-script solution. Currently only the database name is exposed (with <>).
In case of MSSQL 'DBName' and using double ' in case I have a ' in the text works fine.
I am basically looking for the SQLite equivalent.

(attach is done by the framework, so is the script execution, but the aliases are unknown for the script author)

Comment: The alias is not optional when attaching a database in SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Never use single quotes around database/table/column names.
When needed use double quotes or square brackets or backticks.

When attaching the database `A'A` you use an alias like:

```
ATTACH "c:\...path..\A'A.db" AS anything;
```

Use that alias in the `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM anything.MyTable;
```